# How to expand first div always on sorting in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have some divs which are coming from ng repeat.In which first div is open/expanded always on load.Here on click a button I am sorting divs based on id inside json. Every thing is working but when I am sorting my top divs should also be expanded and other divs should be closed.Can anyone please help me.Here is the code below

### html

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.4/angular-filter.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular-sanitize.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js'></script>
<script  src="script.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css'>
 <body ng-app="app">     
  <div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
    <div class="scroll-div">      
      <div style="border:1px solid;" id="anchor{{group.id}}"  ng-repeat="group in groups | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
        <div class="parents"  ng-click="open(group)"><i ng-class="{'glyphicon-minus': group.isOpen, 'glyphicon-plus': !group.isOpen}"></i> {{ group.title }}        
        </div>

        <ul class="childs" ng-show="group.isOpen">
          <li ng-repeat="item in group.list ">
            <span ng-bind-html="item"></span>
          </li>
        </ul>        
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" ng-click="test()">Sort</button>
  </div>
  </body>
```

### script

```
var app=angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap','ngSanitize','angular.filter']);
app.controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function ($scope,$location,$anchorScroll) {
  $scope.oneAtATime = true;

  $scope.open = function (item) {
    $scope.groups.filter(a=> a ===item).forEach(a=>{
      a.isOpen = !a.isOpen;
    });
    $scope.closeOthers(item);

  }

  $scope.closeOthers = function (item) {
    $scope.groups.filter(a=> a !==item).forEach(a=>{
      a.isOpen = false;
    });
  }

  $scope.groups = [
    {
      title: 'title 1',
      id:'1',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 2',
      id:'2',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 3',
      id:'3',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 4',
      id:'4',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]

    },
    {
      title: 'title 5',
      id:'6',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 6',
      id:'5',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
        ]
    }
  ];
  $scope.test = function() {

  $scope.predicate = 'id'; 
  $scope.reverse=true;
  }
$scope.groups[0].isOpen = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use `track by $index` and `ng-show="$index == 0"`.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngSanitize', 'angular.filter']);
app.controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
  $scope.oneAtATime = true;
  $scope.pristine = true;

  $scope.open = function(item) {
    $scope.groups.filter(a => a === item).forEach(a => {
      a.isOpen = !a.isOpen;
    });
    $scope.closeOthers(item);
    $scope.pristine = false;

  }

  $scope.closeOthers = function(item) {
    $scope.groups.filter(a => a !== item).forEach(a => {
      a.isOpen = false;
    });
  }

  $scope.groups = [{
      title: 'title 1',
      id: '1',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
      ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 2',
      id: '2',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
      ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 3',
      id: '3',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
      ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 4',
      id: '4',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
      ]

    },
    {
      title: 'title 5',
      id: '5',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
      ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 6',
      id: '6',
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a',
        'item4a',
        'item5a',
        'item6a',
        'item7a'
      ]
    }
  ];
  $scope.test = function() {
  
    $scope.groups.forEach(a => {a.isOpen = false;});
    $scope.pristine = true;
    
    $scope.predicate = 'id';
    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;

  }
  $scope.groups[0].isOpen = true;
});
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.4/angular-filter.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular-sanitize.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js'></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css'>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
    <div class="scroll-div">
      <div style="border:1px solid;" id="anchor{{group.id}}" ng-repeat="group in groups | orderBy:predicate:reverse track by $index">
        <div class="parents" ng-click="open(group)"><i ng-class="{'glyphicon-minus': group.isOpen, 'glyphicon-plus': !group.isOpen}"></i> {{ group.title }}
        </div>

        <ul class="childs" ng-show="($index == 0 && pristine) || group.isOpen">
          <li ng-repeat="item in group.list ">
            <span ng-bind-html="item"></span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" ng-click="test()">Sort</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.Here if I click on '+'  icon of any div,that div should expand and other should close,earlier it was like that only. sorting is happening but once you sort only top should be exapnd other should close

Comment: Maybe use additional flag. I change my example.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result , use below option

1. Get index of that top most object after sorting items using findIndex array method

   let index = $scope.groups.findIndex(v => v.id == $scope.groups.length);
   $scope.groups[index].isOpen = true;

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/zyQJYx

```js
var app = angular.module("app", [
  "ui.bootstrap",
  "ngSanitize",
  "angular.filter"
]);
app.controller("AccordionDemoCtrl", function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
  $scope.oneAtATime = true;
  
  $scope.open = function (item) {
    $scope.groups.filter(a=> a ===item).forEach(a=>{
      a.isOpen = !a.isOpen;
    });
    $scope.closeOthers(item);

  }

  $scope.closeOthers = function(item) {
    $scope.groups.filter(a => a !== item).forEach(a => {
      a.isOpen = false;
    });
  };

  $scope.groups = [
    {
      title: "title 1",
      id: "1",
      list: [
        "<i>item1a</i> blah blah",
        "item2a",
        "item3a",
        "item4a",
        "item5a",
        "item6a",
        "item7a"
      ]
    },
    {
      title: "title 2",
      id: "2",
      list: [
        "<i>item1a</i> blah blah",
        "item2a",
        "item3a",
        "item4a",
        "item5a",
        "item6a",
        "item7a"
      ]
    },
    {
      title: "title 3",
      id: "3",
      list: [
        "<i>item1a</i> blah blah",
        "item2a",
        "item3a",
        "item4a",
        "item5a",
        "item6a",
        "item7a"
      ]
    },
    {
      title: "title 4",
      id: "4",
      list: [
        "<i>item1a</i> blah blah",
        "item2a",
        "item3a",
        "item4a",
        "item5a",
        "item6a",
        "item7a"
      ]
    },
    {
      title: "title 5",
      id: "6",
      list: [
        "<i>item1a</i> blah blah",
        "item2a",
        "item3a",
        "item4a",
        "item5a",
        "item6a",
        "item7a"
      ]
    },
    {
      title: "title 6",
      id: "5",
      list: [
        "<i>item1a</i> blah blah",
        "item2a",
        "item3a",
        "item4a",
        "item5a",
        "item6a",
        "item7a"
      ]
    }
  ];
  $scope.test = function() {
    $scope.groups[0].isOpen = false;
    $scope.predicate = "id";
    $scope.reverse = true;
    let index = $scope.groups
      .map(function(x) {
        return x.id;
      })
      .indexOf($scope.groups.filter(v => v.id == $scope.groups.length)[0].id);
    $scope.groups[index].isOpen = true;
  };

  $scope.groups[0].isOpen = true;
});
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.4/angular-filter.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular-sanitize.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js'></script>
<script  src="script.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css'>
 <body ng-app="app">     
  <div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
    <div class="scroll-div">      
      <div style="border:1px solid;" id="anchor{{group.id}}"  ng-repeat="group in groups | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
        <div class="parents"  ng-click="open(group)"><i ng-class="{'glyphicon-minus': group.isOpen, 'glyphicon-plus': !group.isOpen}"></i> {{ group.title }}        
        </div>

        <ul class="childs" ng-show="group.isOpen">
          <li ng-repeat="item in group.list ">
            <span ng-bind-html="item"></span>
          </li>
        </ul>        
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" ng-click="test()">Sort</button>
  </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help,Individual collapse/expand is not happening,Earlier it was happening on click of  '+' icon

Comment: just changed logic to the sort button , getting index of top most object after sort